# need a help replace words with php

Tags: php, replace

The original words

```
$string = '<a href="/home/top">here is some text</a>. <a href="/links/abc">some links here</a>...';
//more links and other html. more link like <a href="/home/below">, <a href="/links/def">...
```

I need change to

```
<a href="/links/abc"> => <a href="#" onclick="link('abc|123')">
<a href="/links/def"> => <a href="#" onclick="link('def|123')">
<a href="/links/ghi"> => <a href="#" onclick="link('ghi|123')">
```

I tried to use `str_replace`, but it just easy to replace `<a href="` to `<a href="#" onclick="link('` and hard to judge the next part. but how to deal with these replace? Thanks.

Comment: you can use preg_replace with a regular expression. there are many tutorials for this topic. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php and http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-regular-expression.html

Comment: @Fender, can u write it for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_replace():

```
$string = preg_replace('%href="/links/(.+?)"%', 'href="#" onclick="link(\'$1|123\')"', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

pattern: `$pattern = '@<a href=\"/links/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\">@is';`

replace: `$replace = '<a href="#" onclick="link(\'\1|123\')">';`

call: `$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);`